# Теоретический вопрос по отказу от шаблонов в node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Насколько менее производительным будет скрипт node js, если в проекте полностью отказаться от html файлов (планирую отказаться от шаблонов), а рендерить html напрямую из скрипта а потом отдавать клиенту. Например, есть объект HTML, а теги, это его свойства, скрипт лепит готовый html + встраивает данные из БД и отдаёт клиенту. Рендерить для асинхронности html можно через setImmediate. Теоретически, на сколько это будет тормознутый вариант?

Comment: Вы хотите написать свой, более быстрый шаблонизатор? Успехов)

Comment: Нет, совсем отказать от шаблонов - от файлов html.

Comment: Если не нравятся файлы html - можете выбрать  jade, ejs, hbs, итд, итп

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы когда либо слышали про `React`, то возможно и слышали про `SSR`. Изначально все приложение `React` строится именно с помощью `js`. Поэтому ваш `html` может состоять из всего одного элемента `<div id="app"></div>`

Но из-за этого появились свои проблемы. Мало того, что вам нужно дождаться того, когда загрузится ваша страничка, так и дождаться, когда ваше приложение построится. Так сказать, *"холодный старт"*. Это тоже требует времени и оптимизации. Тогда и появился `SSR`.

Суть его такова, что мы все так же храним наше приложение именно в `js`, но, при первом запросе сайта, сервер у себя на стороне запускает и строит ваше приложение, возвращая уже готовый начальный `html`, так если бы вы его написали прямо в `html`. Следовательно *"холодный запуск"* происходит на сервере, а дальше приложение работает как обычно.

Такая технология работает в связке с `React`, но если вы задумались об этом, можете попробовать реализовать свою реализацию